# printing pie's dataLabels numbers with commas

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm trying to print numbers with commas (showing 9,000 instand of just 9000), this is the way I'm setting the format
`format: '{point.name}: {point.y}'`

I cant find a way to get `{point.y}` into a function that will return the wanted result, 
I tried this way `format: '{point.name}: '+ numberWithCommas(point.y)` but then of course `point is not defined` I'm not sure how to handle it,
any direction how can I make it work ?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- set separator:

  ```
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      decimalPoint: '.',
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
  });
  ```
- set point format, to use that separator:

  ```
  format: '{point.name}: {point.y:,.0f}'
  ```

More about formatting string in Highcharts can be found [in the DOCs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) ;)

And live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3edt5xq1/).